# Casting one generic to another, without class constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

I have the following code:

```
public interface IDrilldown
{
   void AddCriteria<T>(T Criterion);
}

public class MyClass<W> : IDrilldown // where W : class
{
    void IDrilldown.AddCriteria<T>(T Criterion)
    {
       W value = Criterion as W;
       ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the cast I have above will not work unless W has the constaint in the code.  I would like to have this using value types.  Is it at all possible?

I cannot make W and T the same type.  My interface does not have a type associated with it globally, only the internal data types.

This is so that I can have a List all having different T's

Comment: What stops you from calling AddCriteria<int> on a MyClass<string>? The compiler is telling you that you are violating type safety because *you are violating type safety*. Look at it this way: the contract of the IDrilldown interface is that a criterion can be of any type. You can't come along and make an implementation that requires the type to be of type W; in that case you are not implementing the contract. How could the user of the interface know that there is an extra constraint in there that is nowhere in the contract?

Comment: I understand that is the issue.  I'm moreso trying to modify the class design above so that I'm no longer violating the contract.  In the end, I'm basically looking for a List of intefaces, where each one has internal list of varying types value and ref classes.

Comment: What do you need to do with W that requires you to have access to the entire object? Can Criterion be implemented as an interface that describes what you need to do to it? Are you just trying to call `.ToString()` on all of the criterion objects?

Comment: So why not just have a List<object> of criteria then? If a criterion is not guaranteed to be a W, but rather a criterion can be of any type T, then I think List<object> is the best you're going to do.

Comment: I was concerned about the time penalty of packing and unpacking value types.  The list can grow upwards of 500k.

Comment: @Dave, I like that idea actually.  I might give that a try.

Comment: 500 thousand elements, or some smaller number of elements consuming 500 kb of memory? You're going to have a problem with the former no matter what strategy you choose; that's an awfully big list to be keeping in memory. I would choose some strategy other than an in-memory list in that case. If I had half a million items to wrangle I'd be putting them in a database. If you merely mean that you are eating up half a meg of memory, no big deal (for memory; time might still be a problem). You have 2000 megs of virtual address space in a 32 bit process, so half a meg is nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a way to do it, it's a little hacky but allows it to work:

```
class MyClass<W> : IDrilldown {
    void IDrilldown.AddCriteria<T>(T Criterion) {
        if (Criterion is W) {
            W value = (W)Convert.ChangeType(Criterion, typeof(W));
            // value is W, have fun
            // or - as Snowbear pointed out in the comments
            W value = (W)(object)Criterion;
            // works just as well....
        } else {
            // value is NOT W and could not be converted.
        }
    }
}
```

The only drawback with this is, `Convert.ChangeType` will use converters to change between internal objects, so `string value = (string)Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(string))` will work and return `"1"` instead of throwing an exception.

To clarify on how this works, the documentation states:

> For the conversion to succeed, ***value must implement the IConvertible interface***, because the method simply wraps a call to an appropriate IConvertible method. The method requires that conversion of value to conversionType be supported.

so for this method to work with custom types you will need to implement the `IConvertible` interface to convert from one custom type to any other type. In the code sample above, if *both* `T` and `W` are the same type, the `Convert.ChangeType` will succeed, even if the custom object does not implement `IConvertiable`.

Comment: Currently, the only datatypes I'm using are int, String, and enums

Comment: if `Criterion is W` why don't you want to use `W value = (W)(object)Criterion` instead? It seems to be easier.

Comment: @Snowbear: Because... because... ... I... I never thought of it like that. That method reminds me a bit of casting `(void*)` in C  (`reinterpret_cast<void*>` for the C++ folks). Of course, both ways have the same stink because you're telling the compiler to ignore the types... :)

Comment: @Snowbear, it is one of the worst things I would do, but if he doesn't want to have strong typing anyway...

Comment: Are there any performance concerns in the solution mentioned above? If the worst case scenario is that I am unboxing during the addcriteria, its not a big deal.

Comment: Based on his comments, apparently the point of this exercise is to avoid a boxing penalty; in that case, neither solution is good because they both involve expensive operations.

Comment: The point of the exersize was to allow the application do work with both ref and value types.  In hindsight, I'm realizing I can't have BOTH without the boxing penalty on value types, which is kind of my bad.  The solution above works great.  I may have to revisit when we run large-scale tests for performance.  If that becomes an issue, the best solution I think is to have all the possible data types (int, enum, string, etc) have a wrapper class that implements a GetValue() function or something similar.  Thanks everyone for the help and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Would the dynamic keyword help you out?

Something like this:

```
public interface IDrilldown
{
   void AddCriteria<T>(T Criterion);
}

public class MyClass : IDrilldown
{
    void IDrilldown.AddCriteria<T>(T criterion)
    {
       dynamic value = criterion;
       // can use typeof() to figure out type if needed...
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in .net 2.0 (c++). Thanks though.